# Using Python calculate an employee tenure with a company X

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, date-difference

I have a situation where I need to calculate an employee's tenure with a company X in years. The data is available in the below format:

df =

```
EID      Event_Name                Event_Date
1        Hired                     03/09/1990  00:00:00
1        Terminated                14/10/2005  00:00:00
1        Rehired                   02/11/2015  00:00:00
2        Hired                     03/10/1990  00:00:00
2        Terminated                15/10/2005  00:00:00
```

Tenure calculation is easy enough to understand :

**First calculate the difference between Hired and Terminated 
Second Calculate the difference between today's date and Rehired (if rehired is applicable other wise ignore)**

Example : For EID =1 : the tenure is:

```
  (LAST JOB WORKED WITH COMPANY X)         14/10/2005  00:00:00 - 03/09/1990  00:00:00 = 5520 days
  (REHIRED WITH COMP X AND STILL WORKING)  25/04/2020  00:00:00 - 02/11/2015  00:00:00 = 1636 days
```

**Total tenure in days = (5520 + 1636)/365 = 19.6 years**
and similarly for other EIDs as well

The output should look like the following:

```
 EID      Tenure(Years)               
 1        19.6
 2        15.04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution working if never consecutive `Terminated` values per groups in `Event_Name` column:

```
#converting to datetimes
df['Event_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event_Date'], dayfirst=True)

#today datetime
now = pd.Timestamp.now().floor('d')
#shifted rows per groups for terminated Event_Date 
df['new'] = df.groupby('EID')['Event_Date'].shift(-1).fillna(now)
#removed rows with Terminated
df = df[df['Event_Name'].ne('Terminated')].copy() 
#difference
df['Tenure(Years)'] = df['new'].sub(df['Event_Date'])
#aggregate sum
df = df.groupby('EID')['Tenure(Years)'].sum().dt.days.div(365).reset_index()
print (df)
   EID  Tenure(Years)
0    1      19.605479
1    2      15.043836
```

Comment: Let me quickly check this and I will let you know!

Comment: @Django0602 - If some problem with solution I think reason is different order of `Event_Name` values

Comment: this is simply amazing! Thank you so much @jezrael! It is working properly as there are no events where termination appears consecutively for any ID.